# Synchronize GPS orientation with cameras

Tags: slam, mapping, calibration, gps

I'm interested in using GPS system to generate ground truth for evaluation of some SLAM systems I am testing.

I'm confused on how I can initialize the location and orientation of the GPS unit to be consistent with the other sensor systems?

How does the kitti dataset do it? If the starting orientation is just a little off the maps will diverge drastically. How do the existing datasets do it?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but by "orientation" do you mean "direction"?  GPS systems can only derived direction through evaluating two different locations.  That is, getting a location, traveling in a straight line and getting another location.  Further, unless you are spending a lot of money, most common off the shelf GPS modules only provide about +/- 5 meters on a good day (good weather, good space weather & view of sky from horizon to horizon).

Comment: Initial pose, the problem is if your SLAM world coordinates aren't aligned with the GPS system you end up deviating off if you travel very far. This is because the orientations don't align.